# wokflow: Missing cloudify_agent.queue runtime information

Tags: docker, cloudify

I want to install a Docker container on Cloudify and wrote a blueprint with docker-plugin (attached at the end).

At the beginning, I finished the blueprint by learning [CloudifyDocs](http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.0/plugins/docker/#cloudify-docker-container). But when it came to installing the workflow, an error occurred with the message

`'install' workflow execution failed: RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'docker_plugin.tasks.create_container' -> Missing cloudify_agent.queue runtime information. This most likely means that the Compute node was never started successfully`

I thought something went wrong in my file, so I tried to deploy and install [cloudify-nodecellar-docker-example](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-nodecellar-docker-example/blob/master/simple-blueprint.yaml). But the IP address was not OK and I finally changed the inputs to

`host_ip: 10.10.1.10
agent_user: vagrant
agent_private_key_path: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa`

, which is taken from a Cloudify beginner example. Unfortunately, the RuntimeError showed up again.

Now I'm at loss of which part I've missed. Any opinion is welcomed!

---

```
    tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3

    imports:
      - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/3.4.1/types.yaml
      - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/docker-plugin/1.3.2/plugin.yaml

    inputs:
      host_ip:
        description: >
          the ip of the host the application will be deployed on
        default: 10.10.1.10
      container_port_binding:
        description: >
          a dict of port bindings for the node container.
        default:
          6633: 6633
      agent_user:
          description: >
            User name used when SSH-ing into the started machine

      agent_private_key_path:
          description: >
            Path to a private key that resided on the management machine.
            SSH-ing into agent machines will be done with this key.

    node_templates:
      host:
        type: cloudify.nodes.Compute
        properties:
          install_agent: false
          ip: { get_input: host_ip }
          cloudify_agent:
            user: { get_input: agent_user }
            key: { get_input: agent_private_key_path }
      client:
        type: cloudify.docker.Container
        properties: 
          name: ryu
          image:
            repository: muzixing/ryu
            tags: RYU
        interfaces:
          cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
            create:
              implementation: docker.docker_plugin.tasks.create_container
              inputs:
                params:
                  stdin_open: true
                  tty: true
                  command: /bin/bash
            start:
              implementation: docker.docker_plugin.tasks.start
              inputs:
                params:
                  port_bindings: { get_input: container_port_binding }
        relationships:
          - type: cloudify.relationships.contained_in
            target: host

    outputs: #this part may be questionable but seems less important?
      endpoint:
        value:
          ip_address: { get_prperty: [ host , ip ]}
          port:  { get_input: container_port_binding }
      #status:
        #value: { "the container is running" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Later on I solved this problem and moved on.
And now, I'd like to share my opinions.
`Missing runtime information` that's mainly for the lack of agent, who is responsible for receiving missions.

So input `install_agent` as `true`, and the trouble is gone.